# My add-in block when I use Office.js

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-js

I have an add-in who execute js function. And I use this code to show notification and deug.

```
function statusUpdate(icon, text) {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("status", {
    type: "informationalMessage",
    icon: icon,
    message: text,
    persistent: false
  });
}
```

In my initialise function I do this

```
statusUpdate("icon16", Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId);
```

But I have the notification who say my add-in load to do the work.

If I put a string directly my notification works. An idea why my add-in block ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Comment: I don't see why/where  my question is not clear

Comment: @Mark Are you calling `replaceAsync` to replace an existing notification? If you just want to display a notification, kindly call `addAsync`. If that is not working, kindly let me know.  
On a totally un-related issue, kindly use `Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage` for the type of the notification instead of a literal string.

Comment: I use replaceAsync, because I saw a code who use that to display notification. I changed with addAsync like you suggest. But it didn't working. Have you an idea why I can use a string, but not Office.js return ?

Answer (score 0):

Does addAsync not work for you or it works with string, while not with Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId? What error do you get? The maximum length for message is 150 characters, while Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId could be longer than that.